# Material Sidenav isn't animating

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-sidenav` setup:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav opened mode="side" #sideNav>
    <app-sidenav-header (triggerSidenav)="triggerSidenav($event)"></app-sidenav-header>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-header></app-header>

    <div class="main-content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and triggering the toggle:

```
  triggerSidenav(event) {
    this.sideNav.toggle();
  }
```

The sidenav will close as but there's no animation and the `mat-sidenav-content` doesn't change width either.

I have the `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` imported in my `app.module.ts` file.

My `MatSidenavModule` is part of a `mat-component.module` file in a shared folder. I have that imported into my `app.module` file as well.

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz to reproduce this ?

Comment: is there any error in console ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda nope

Comment: @Aravind working on it

Comment: @Aravind I made one and it works... so... I'm even more lost now. lol

Comment: it's almost like `BrowserAnimationsModule` isn't loading?

Comment: @dcp3450 hahaha stuff happens, you need more help?

Comment: @Aravind I mean... yea but I can't even figure out what with since the stackblitz worked but my local doesn't. :/ lol

Comment: yes! make sense. try updating your `node_modules` and doing a clean build

Comment: @Aravind tried that to no avail

Comment: @dcp3450 Unfortunately I have to debug and then I will be able to figure out what's the actual problem

Comment: @Aravind see my answer

Comment: @dcp3450 finding that would be so frustating! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update the Material version. My app is Anguar v9 and Material was v6.